# Примеры как сделать вход и регистрацию на сайте Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Привет, хочу на сайте сделать регистрацию и вход(логин пароль), прочитал документацию, идея понятная, но как всё организовать не ясно. Есть ли где-то пошаговое описание реализации или что-то подобное как это организовать?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что stackoverflow это не гугл, нужно сначала найти какое-то решение, реализовать его и если что-то не получится писать уже сюда.

Comment: Тут довольно подробно все показано: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PBp2UqWEv0 **UPD:** Про Yii2: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-integrating-user-registration--cms-22974 к слову это след.ссылка в гугле :)

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, но это для yii 1

Comment: Нашел хорошее видео где подробно рассказано об этом.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYOcEVlv9l0

Comment: В basic приложении уже реализована авторизация. Просто добавьте форму регистрации, которая будет записывать данные в таблицу пользователей.

Comment: Поддерживаю закрытие ... Но ссылку оставлю :) , очень уж помогла она мне, думаю, поможет и другим: [тыц](https://youtu.be/z5kCMKglZWc?list=PLa9lO_Eq-vZV7GQtlFyMQcHPTssEOP7Nq).

Comment: Если тема останется, то подробно распишу весь процесс:)

Comment: Буду рад прочитать)